# Correct way to move player in cocos2d-x chipmunk platformer

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, chipmunk

I'm attempting to make a physics based 2d platformer in cocos2d-x using the built in chipmunk physics engine.  I've not used a physics engine before and I'm having some issues setting the correct values (mass, friction, etc...) for my physics bodies so that I can make the player move correctly.  The problem that I'm facing is that when I add any amount of friction to either the tilemap bodies or the player body, the player moves so slowly that it's almost not visible.

Right now I'm loading a TMXTileMap and creating a PhysicsBody for each tile and a PhysicsBody for the player.  Relevant code for player physics body material:

```
 auto physicsBody = PhysicsBody::createCircle(this->getContentSize().width, PhysicsMaterial(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

relevant code for tile map physics bodies:

```
auto physicsBody = PhysicsBody::createBox(tileSprite->getContentSize(), PhysicsMaterial(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
physicsBody->setDynamic(false);
physicsBody->setGravityEnable(false);
```

And here is how I'm trying to move the player:

```
void Player::onKeyPressed(EventKeyboard::KeyCode keyCode, Event* event) {
    log("Key with keycode %d pressed", keyCode);
    switch(keyCode){
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_LEFT_ARROW:
            _impulseX += -700.0f;
            break;
        case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:
            _impulseX += 700.0f;
            break;
    }
}

void Player::update(float dt) {
    this->getPhysicsBody()->applyImpulse(Vec2(_impulseX * dt, _impulseY * dt));
}
```

I currently have all of the PhysicsMaterial values set to 0.0f.  Without setting those to 0 I can't get the player to move, but when they are set at 0 the player appears as if he's moving on ice and there is no friction to slow it down.  Is there something wrong with the way I'm moving the player?  Or is there something wrong with my PhysicsMaterial?

note: I'm not currently using a fixed timestep but plan to in the future.  Could this be causing my problem?

**edit**:  I've read a few places that it's better to use surface velocity to move a character but I can't find any examples of doing that.  Is it possible using cocos2d-x?

Comment: When using a physics engine, it's always better to use a fixed timestep.